# problem on filing up the colour between two index values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a timeseries data `timeseries.txt`. First I select a index value (here 50) and put a red line mark on that selected index value. And I want to highlight  portion before(idx-20) and after(idx+20) the red line index value on the timeseries.

I wrote this code however i am able to put the red line mark on the timeseries but while using `fill_betweenx` it doesnot work. I hope experts may help me overcoming this problem.Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

input_data=np.loadtxt("timeseries.txt")
time=np.arange(len(input_data))
plt.plot(time,input_data)
idx = [50]
mark = [time[i] for i in idx]
plt.plot(idx,[input_data[i] for i in mark], marker="|",color='red',markerfacecolor='none',mew=0.4,ms=30,alpha=2.0)
plt.fill_betweenx(idx-20,idx+20 alpha=0.25,color='lightsteelblue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When you say `highlight portion before(idx-20) and after(idx+20) `, are you expecting to see a rectangular box?

Comment: yes @Redox u r right,,please suggest a solution'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for just a semi-transparent rectangle, you can use `patches.Rectangle` to draw one. Refer [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html). I have updated your code to add a rectangle. See if this meets your requirement. I have used a sine wave as I didn't have your data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## Create sine wave
x = np.arange(100)
input_data=np.sin(2*np.pi*3*x/100)
time=np.arange(len(input_data))
plt.plot(time,input_data)
idx = [50]
mark = [time[i] for i in idx]
plt.plot(idx,[input_data[i] for i in mark], marker="|", color='red', markerfacecolor='none', mew=0.4,ms=30,alpha=2.0)
#plt.fill_betweenx(mark,idx-20,0, alpha=0.25,color='lightsteelblue')

# Create a Rectangle patch
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((idx[0]-20, -0.15), 40, .3, facecolor = 'lightsteelblue',fill=True,alpha=0.25, lw=0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Please refer to the Rectangle documentation provided earlier in the response. You will need to adjust the start coordinates (x,y) and the height and width to see how big/small you need the Rectangle. For eg: changing the rectangle code like this...

```
plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((idx[0]-10, -0.40), 20, 0.8, facecolor = 'lightsteelblue',fill=True,alpha=0.25, lw=0))
```

will give you this plot.

[image]

Comment: how the rectange should be vertical, just around the red vertical line @Redox

Comment: Read the link for rectangle and understand the coordinates, width and height. You can adjust it to suit where you want the rectangle and its height and width. I have added a little code in EDIT section of response above to showcase how the pic will change by changing x,y,h,w. Hope this helps